# How to fetch highest value item from SharePoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, caml

I created a Custom List in developer Site. In that List I created a column called `Totalsumma` and added some numeric items like "324", "567" etc. How can I fetch the highest value from that column.

```
    function totalSumma() {
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var textCaml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='fmld' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
    query.set_viewXml(textCaml);
    var items = listitemCollection.getItems(query);
    context.load(items)

    context.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfail);
    context.load(listitemCollection);

    function onsuccess() {

        var innerHtml = '';
        var enumerator = listitemCollection.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
            innerHtml += "<br/>" + currentListItem.get_item('fmld');
        }

        $("#Visa4").html(innerHtml);
    }

    function onfail() {
        alert("wrong");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query

```
<View>
    <Query>        
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name='fmld' Ascending='FALSE' />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Then use

```
query.set_viewXml(query)
items = list.getItems(query)
context.load(items)
```

**Updated based on answer edit**

```
function totalSumma() {
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var textCaml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='fmld' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
    query.set_viewXml(textCaml);
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(items);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfail);
    function onsuccess() {
        var innerHtml = '';
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
            innerHtml += "<br/>" + currentListItem.get_item('fmld');
        }
        $("#Visa4").html(innerHtml);
    }
    function onfail() {
        alert("wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey I used it but it displays: "1" in the div. Any wrong with my function?

Comment: Doesnt work : (

Comment: Ok I have updated now.

Comment: `var listitemCollection = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("SpTenta1Uppg2").getItems("");`

Comment: That code is global.

Comment: Yes I already have it as global variable: 
 `var listitemCollection = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("SpTenta1Uppg2").getItems("");`

Comment: What you have is `SPListItemCollection`.. for retrieving item based on CAML you need a `SPList` object.. Please read about SharePoint programming model.

Comment: I put this inside my function and it displays `var list = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("SpTenta1Uppg2");` But I dont get the highest value. It gives me the first value from the column.

Comment: So it works but displays not the highest value but it displays the first value.

Comment: Need 5 more rep to be able to vote up.